# Remove Touch/Click Behavior

Tags: java, android

I would like to remove the click behavior from this activity. In the attached screenshot if you touch/click the contact name the app crashes(the edit button works properly). However, I really don't care to fix this error, I would rather remove the touch/click behavior of that area. I also need to be able to retain the ability to select a contact on the add contacts activity. I have attached a screenshot, My Contacts Activity, Add Contacts Activity, and the adaptor. Is there anything else needed?

**Screenshot**
[image: ![enter image description here]

**My Contacts Activity**

```
public class MyContactsActivity extends BaseAppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyContactsActivity";

    private final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 9001;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private IndexFastScrollRecyclerView recyclerContacts;
    private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ContactInfo> mLegalContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void startActivity(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyContactsActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_contacts);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        recyclerContacts = (IndexFastScrollRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.contact_recycler);
        //recyclerContacts.setIndexTextSize(12);
        recyclerContacts.setIndexBarTextColor(String.format("#%X", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.mainColor)));
        recyclerContacts.setIndexBarColor(String.format("#%X", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)));
        recyclerContacts.setIndexbarMargin(0);
        recyclerContacts.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerContacts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerContacts.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        checkAndAskPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, LegalEqualizerApp.READ_CONTACTS_REQUEST_CODE, permissionDelegate);
    }

    private Delegate.PermissionDelegate permissionDelegate = new Delegate.PermissionDelegate() {
        @Override
        public void granted(int requestCode) {
            super.granted(requestCode);
            mLegalContacts = getLegalContacts();
            mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(mLegalContacts, null);
            recyclerContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void denied(int requestCode) {
            super.denied(requestCode);
            showDialog(getString(R.string.title_permission), getString(R.string.permission_contact));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.edit:
                AddContactsActivity.startActivityForResult(MyContactsActivity.this, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            checkAndAskPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, LegalEqualizerApp.READ_CONTACTS_REQUEST_CODE, permissionDelegate);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<ContactInfo> getLegalContacts() {

        showProgress(getString(R.string.please_wait));

        ArrayList<ContactInfo> legalContacts = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> contacts = loadLegalContacts();

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            if (phoneNumber != null) {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(")", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("+", "");
            }
            if (contacts.contains(id)) {
                ContactInfo info = new ContactInfo(id, name, phoneNumber);
                boolean isNew = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < legalContacts.size(); i++) {
                    if (TextUtils.equals(legalContacts.get(i).name, name)) {
                        isNew = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isNew) {
                    legalContacts.add(info);
                }
            }
        }
        phones.close();

        hideProgress();

        return legalContacts;
    }

    private List<String> loadLegalContacts() {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> set = SharedPrefUtil.getInstance().getStringSet("LegalContacts");
        if (set != null) {
            contacts.addAll(set);
        }

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Contacts Adaptor Java

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements SectionIndexer {
    public interface OnContactListItemActionInterface {
        void onContactItemClicked(int position);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ContactsAdapter";

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_CONTACT = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 2;
    private OnContactListItemActionInterface clickListener = null;
    ArrayList<ContactInfo> mContactsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mSectionPositions;

    private ArrayList<String> mSelectedIDs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        List<String> sections = new ArrayList<>();
        mSectionPositions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0, size = mContactsArray.size(); i < size; i++) {
            if (TextUtils.equals(mContactsArray.get(i).id, "-1")) {
                sections.add(String.valueOf(mContactsArray.get(i).name.charAt(0)).toUpperCase());
                mSectionPositions.add(i);
            }
        }
        return sections.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public void setOnContactItemListener(OnContactListItemActionInterface listener) {
        this.clickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
        return mSectionPositions.get(sectionIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public ContactsAdapter(ArrayList<ContactInfo> arrContacts, ArrayList<String> selectedIDs) {
        if (selectedIDs == null) {
            this.mSelectedIDs = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            this.mSelectedIDs = selectedIDs;
        }
        this.mContactsArray = convertContacts(arrContacts);
    }

    private ArrayList<ContactInfo> convertContacts(ArrayList<ContactInfo> arrContacts) {
        ArrayList<ContactInfo> newArray = new ArrayList<>();
        char currentChar = ' ';
        char lastChar = ' ';

        if (mSelectedIDs.size() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrContacts.size(); i++) {
                if (arrContacts.get(i).isSelected()) {
                    mSelectedIDs.add(arrContacts.get(i).id);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrContacts.size(); i++) {
            if (arrContacts.get(i).name == null) continue;
            currentChar = Character.toUpperCase(arrContacts.get(i).name.charAt(0));
            if (newArray.size() == 0) {
                if (Character.isLetter(currentChar)) {
                    newArray.add(new ContactInfo("-1", String.valueOf(currentChar), "0"));
                    lastChar = currentChar;
                } else {
                    newArray.add(new ContactInfo("-1", "#", "0"));
                    lastChar = '#';
                }
            } else if (currentChar != lastChar) {
                if (Character.isLetter(currentChar)) {
                    newArray.add(new ContactInfo("-1", String.valueOf(currentChar), "0"));
                    lastChar = currentChar;
                } else {
                    newArray.add(new ContactInfo("-1", "#", "0"));
                    lastChar = '#';
                }
            }
            newArray.add(arrContacts.get(i));
        }

        return newArray;
    }

    public boolean onClickItem(int position) {
        if (!TextUtils.equals(mContactsArray.get(position).id, "-1")) {
            if (mContactsArray.get(position).isSelected()) {
                mContactsArray.get(position).unSelect();
                mSelectedIDs.remove(mContactsArray.get(position).id);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                return true;
            } else if (mSelectedIDs == null || mSelectedIDs.size() < 5) {
                mContactsArray.get(position).select();
                mSelectedIDs.add(mContactsArray.get(position).id);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int getSelectedCount() {
        if (mSelectedIDs == null || mSelectedIDs.size() == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return mSelectedIDs.size();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSelectedContacts() {
        return mSelectedIDs;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_header, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final ContactInfo contact = mContactsArray.get(position);

        if (!TextUtils.equals(contact.id, "-1")) {
            ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) holder;

            contactViewHolder.txtName.setText(contact.name);

            if (mContactsArray.size()-1 <= position || (mContactsArray.size()-1 > position && TextUtils.equals(mContactsArray.get(position+1).id, "-1"))) {
                contactViewHolder.splitView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                contactViewHolder.splitView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (contact.isSelected()) {
                contactViewHolder.imgChecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                contactViewHolder.imgChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            contactViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickListener.onContactItemClicked(position);
                }
            });
        } else {
            HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;

            headerViewHolder.txtName.setText(contact.name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContactsArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        final ContactInfo contact = mContactsArray.get(position);

        if (TextUtils.equals(contact.id, "-1")) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_HEADER;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_CONTACT;
        }
    }

    private static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtName;
        private ImageView imgChecked;
        private View splitView;
        public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            imgChecked = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checked_image);
            splitView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.split_line);
        }
    }

    private static class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtName;
        public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Add Contacts Activity**

```
    public class AddContactsActivity extends BaseAppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AddContactsActivity";

    private IndexFastScrollRecyclerView recyclerContacts;
    private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;
    private EditText mEditSearch;
    private TextView mTxtCancel;
    private ArrayList<ContactInfo> mAllContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    public static void startActivity(Context context, boolean fromNewUser) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddContactsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("NewUser", fromNewUser);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static void startActivityForResult(Activity activity, int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, AddContactsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("NewUser", false);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contacts);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
//        if (!getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("NewUser")) {
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//        }

        mEditSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        mTxtCancel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_cancel);
        mEditSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                filterContacts(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mEditSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    mTxtCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        mTxtCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mEditSearch.setText("");
                hideSoftKeyboard();
                mEditSearch.clearFocus();
                mTxtCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        recyclerContacts = (IndexFastScrollRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.contact_recycler);
        //recyclerContacts.setIndexTextSize(12);
        recyclerContacts.setIndexBarTextColor(String.format("#%X", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.mainColor)));
        recyclerContacts.setIndexBarColor(String.format("#%X", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)));
        recyclerContacts.setIndexbarMargin(0);
        recyclerContacts.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerContacts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerContacts.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

//        recyclerContacts.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
//                return false;
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
//
//            }
//        });
//        recyclerContacts.addOnItemTouchListener(
//                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerContacts, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
//
//                    @Override
//                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
//                        int number = mAdapter.getSelectedCount();
//                        boolean retValue = mAdapter.onClickItem(position);
//                        if (!retValue) {
//                            if (number >= 5) {
//                                showErrorDialog("No more than 5 contacts can be added.");
//                            }
//                        }
//                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(position));
//                    }
//
//                    @Override
//                    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
//                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(position));
//                    }
//                })
//        );

        checkAndAskPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, LegalEqualizerApp.READ_CONTACTS_REQUEST_CODE, permissionDelegate);
    }

    private void contactClickHandler(int pos) {
        int number = mAdapter.getSelectedCount();
        boolean retValue = mAdapter.onClickItem(pos);
        if (!retValue) {
            if (number >= 5) {
                showErrorDialog("No more than 5 contacts can be added.");
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(pos));
    }

    private void filterContacts(CharSequence filter) {

        if (filter.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<ContactInfo> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mAllContacts.size(); i++) {
                String name = mAllContacts.get(i).name.toLowerCase();
                if (name.contains(filter.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    contacts.add(mAllContacts.get(i));
                }
            }
            mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts, mAdapter.getSelectedContacts());
            mAdapter.setOnContactItemListener(new ContactsAdapter.OnContactListItemActionInterface() {
                @Override
                public void onContactItemClicked(int position) {
                    contactClickHandler(position);
                }
            });
            recyclerContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(mAllContacts, mAdapter.getSelectedContacts());
            mAdapter.setOnContactItemListener(new ContactsAdapter.OnContactListItemActionInterface() {
                @Override
                public void onContactItemClicked(int position) {
                    contactClickHandler(position);
                }
            });
            recyclerContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }

    private Delegate.PermissionDelegate permissionDelegate = new Delegate.PermissionDelegate() {
        @Override
        public void granted(int requestCode) {
            super.granted(requestCode);
            mAllContacts = getAllContacts();
            mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(mAllContacts, null);
            mAdapter.setOnContactItemListener(new ContactsAdapter.OnContactListItemActionInterface() {
                @Override
                public void onContactItemClicked(int position) {
                    contactClickHandler(position);
                }
            });
            recyclerContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void denied(int requestCode) {
            super.denied(requestCode);
            showDialog(getString(R.string.title_permission), getString(R.string.permission_contact));
        }
    };

    private ArrayList<ContactInfo> getAllContacts() {

        showProgress(getString(R.string.please_wait));

        List<String> contacts = loadLegalContacts();

        ArrayList<ContactInfo> allContacts = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            if (phoneNumber != null) {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(")", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("+", "");
            }
            ContactInfo info;
            if (contacts.contains(id)) {
                info = new ContactInfo(id, name, phoneNumber, true);
            } else {
                info = new ContactInfo(id, name, phoneNumber);
            }
            boolean isNew = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < allContacts.size(); i++) {
                if (TextUtils.equals(allContacts.get(i).name, name)) {
                    isNew = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isNew) {
                allContacts.add(info);
            }
        }
        phones.close();

        hideProgress();

        return allContacts;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.done, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("NewUser")) {
                    showConfirmDialog(getString(R.string.setting_item_signout), getString(R.string.message_signout), new Delegate.DialogDelegate() {
                        @Override
                        public void complete(int result) {
                            super.complete(result);
                            if (result == RESULT_OK) {
                                FirebaseManager.signOut();
                                //MainActivity.startActivity(SettingsActivity.this);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.done:
                if (saveLegalContacts()) {
                    if (getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("NewUser")) {
                        Home2Activity.startActivity(AddContactsActivity.this);
                    } else {
                        setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    }
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("NewUser")) {
            showConfirmDialog(getString(R.string.setting_item_signout), getString(R.string.message_signout), new Delegate.DialogDelegate() {
                @Override
                public void complete(int result) {
                    super.complete(result);
                    if (result == RESULT_OK) {
                        FirebaseManager.signOut();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private boolean saveLegalContacts() {
        if (mAllContacts.size() > 0) {
            List<String> contacts = mAdapter.getSelectedContacts();
            if (contacts == null || contacts.size() == 0) {
                showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.error_no_contacts));
                return false;
            } else {
                Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
                set.addAll(mAdapter.getSelectedContacts());
                return SharedPrefUtil.getInstance().saveStringSet("LegalContacts", set);
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private List<String> loadLegalContacts() {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> set = SharedPrefUtil.getInstance().getStringSet("LegalContacts");
        if (set != null) {
            contacts.addAll(set);
        }

        return contacts;
    }

}
```

Comment: Comment out the line containing `contactViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(...` to remove the click functionality.  The error is simply `clickListener` is not initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I commented out the code you suggested. However it brings up a second problem. I can no longer add contacts when I hit the edit button.

Comment: I see - well you'll need to figure out what is supposed to be calling `setOnContactItemListener` - or just restore the original code and add a `if (clickListener != null)` before the `clickListener.onContactItemClicked` call.

Comment: As you were replying I added the Add Contacts Activity to the original post if that helps.

Comment: Adding the if statement seems to have worked out great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the logic that handles the response to click events, i.e

1. Remove OnContactListItemActionInterface interface and also the line that creates and instance
   variable of this interface from ContactsAdaptor.java class
2. setOnContactItemListener method from ContactsAdaptor.java class
3. and the onClickListener method inside onBindViewHolder method inside ContactsAdaptor.java class

Comment: Thanks for your response. And thanks for letting know about the addContacts activity. It has been corrected. So, I should just remove all that you suggest and build and run?

Comment: Do you want to respond to recyclerview click events? If no, then remove all the code that I suggested (as adding clickListener would be of no use if you dont want to respond to the click events) and then refactor your code accordingly. If you want to respond to recyclerview click events then don't remove those codes.

Comment: what I want is for the My Contact screen to not respond but I also want/need to be able to add contacts on the Add Contacts screen